# WSO2 PayloadFactory mediator

Tags: json, wso2

I am facing issue while converting xml to json by using payloadfactory mediator.

the xml structure is containing

```
<base>tyuä</base>
```

and it should be transformed into

```
"base":"tyuä"
```

here is the snippet of my code :::

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>
      {
"base": ""
}
</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//base/text()"/>
</args>
         </payloadFactory>
```

But it is giving me as "base":"tyu├ñ".
What should be done to resolve it??

Comment: where do you see the wrong encoding? In the log output or in the message response? (did you try to log the XML before the payload factory if the input is already correct?)

Comment: actually in wso2logs the xml structure is showing as <base>tyu├ñ</base> which causes the output as "base":"tyu├ñ".
But I want output as "base":"tyu├ñ" as per requirement.

Comment: as well please see what is the REAL message output (response), not just wso2log. The log (console) may screw up encoding of the displayed characters, but the message itself may be ok

Comment: the output response is getting affected due to this modified data.this should be actual one

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `messageType` (with `charset=UTF-8`) like this, after the payload factory mediator.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" scope="axis2"/>
```